# Difference LongStream VS Stream in Collectors.toList()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Why when I am getting a list from a `LongStream` with `Collectors.toList()` got an error but with `Stream` there is no error?

Examples :

ERROR :

```
Something.mapToLong(Long::parseLong).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Correct :

```
Something.map(Long::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are four distinct classes in Stream API: `Stream`, `IntStream`, `LongStream` and `DoubleStream`. The latter three are used to process the primitive values `int`, `long` and `double` for better performance. They are tailored for these primitive types and their methods differ much from the `Stream` methods. For example, there's a `LongStream.sum()` method, but there's no `Stream.sum()` method, because you cannot sum any types of objects. The primitive streams don't work with collectors as collectors are accepting objects (there are no special primitive collectors in JDK).

The `Stream` class can be used to process any objects including primitive type wrapper classes like `Integer`, `Long` and `Double`. As you want to collect to the `List<Long>`, then you don't need a stream of `long` primitives, but stream of `Long` objects. So you need `Stream<Long>` and `map` instead of `mapToLong`. The `mapToLong` can be useful, for example, if you need a primitive `long[]` array:

```
long[] result = Something.mapToLong(Long::valueOf).toArray();
```

Comment: I am new to Java stream operations, but can I add this?  If you already have a stream of primitives (e.g. `LongStream`) and want to use `collect(Collectors.toList())` with the stream, you can first box the primitives in the stream using the `Stream.boxed()` operation.  That is `aLongStream.boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())`